# Flex with Rails, just want to update a record....how hard can this be?

Tags: apache-flex

I have this in Flex:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="update"
 url="http://localhost:3000/people/{grid.selectedItem.id}.xml?_method=put" 
 contentType="application/xml"
 resultFormat="e4x"
 method="POST"
 result="index.send()"/>
```

And when it fires I get the following error in Rails:

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-12-07 05:33:55) [POST]
  Parameters: {"person"=>{"first_name"=>"Paul", "last_name"=>"Goulart"}}

ActionController::MethodNotAllowed (Only get, put, and delete requests are allowed.):
  -e:2:in `load'
  -e:2
```

If I edit the same record using scaffolding provided by rails it works:

```
Processing PeopleController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-12-07 05:37:08) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"MV9lFxBGxPgqP0WRTqEWa9/8D36ZzX9opk0SzJ3hUjA=", "id"=>"2", "person"=>{"first_name"=>"Paul", "address"=>"San Francisco", "last_name"=>"Goulart"}}
  [4;35;1mPerson Columns (8.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `people`[0m
  [4;36;1mPerson Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM `people` WHERE (`people`.`id` = 2) [0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0mBEGIN[0m
  [4;36;1mPerson Update (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mUPDATE `people` SET `first_name` = 'Paul', `updated_at` = '2009-12-07 13:37:08' WHERE `id` = 2[0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (1.0ms)[0m   [0mCOMMIT[0m
```

This should be an easy thing.  Just trying to update data from flex using xml.

I'm stuck.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Paul

Comment: what is `index` by the way? is that another http service?

Comment: Did you try with `contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post _method parameter.
It isn't accepting the _GET for the method parameter, and returning that only GET, PUT, and DELETE requests are allowed for this route.

Answer (score 0):

> `Only get, put, and delete requests are allowed.`

change `method="POST"` to `method="PUT"` or `method="GET"`

```
<mx:HTTPService id="update"
 url="http://localhost:3000/people/{grid.selectedItem.id}.xml?_method=put" 
 contentType="application/xml"
 resultFormat="e4x"
 method="GET"
 result="index.send()"/>
```

`HTTPService` [supports](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#method) `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, `PUT`, `TRACE` and `DELETE` methods.

Comment: for some reason that didn't work either, it still thinks I'm sending a post.  By the way the result="update.send()"

If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it or better yet if someone has an example of simple CRUD using RubyAMF or simple REST that would be so helpful.

Do I have to do something in routes to make it accept the update?  I'm so frustrated.

Comment: Note that HTTPService only supports GET and POST unless you use a server based proxy-service (which I think means BlazeDs / LiveCycleDs).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally figured out how to do a RESTful CRUD in Flex with Ruby on Rails.  Thanks everybody who responded.  I've been studying the Flex on Rails book by Tony Hillerson and Daniel Wanja.  Somehow I couldn't get it to work.  The delete wasn't working because in their example they had a delete and my method was called destroy.  Anyways, it's a good book and I thought I'd share how I got to the solution that works.  Turns out it was just adding in the update or destroy convention in the HTTPService tags.

**Create the scaffolding for Account**

script/generate scaffold Account name:string
(You may have to do a db:create or db:migrate)

**The Accounts Controller looks like this:**

class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.find(:all)
    render :xml => @accounts
  end

def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      render :xml => @account, :status => :created, :location => @account
    else
      render :xml => @account.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
      head :ok
    else
      render :xml => @account.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

# DELETE /accounts/1
  # DELETE /accounts/1.xml
  def destroy
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    @account.destroy
    head :ok
  end
end

**Routes.rb looks like this:**

ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :accounts
  map.connect 'accounts/:id', :controller => 'accounts', :action => 'update'
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.

# Sample of regular route:
  #   map.connect 'products/:id', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

# Sample of named route:
  #   map.purchase 'products/:id/purchase', :controller => 'catalog', :action => 'purchase'
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

# Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   map.resources :products

# Sample resource route with options:
  #   map.resources :products, :member => { :short => :get, :toggle => :post }, :collection => { :sold => :get }

# Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   map.resources :products, :has_many => [ :comments, :sales ], :has_one => :seller

# Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   map.resources :products do |products|
  #     products.resources :comments
  #     products.resources :sales, :collection => { :recent => :get }
  #   end

# Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     admin.resources :products
  #   end

# You can have the root of your site routed with map.root -- just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # map.root :controller => "welcome"

# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

# Install the default routes as the lowest priority.
  # Note: These default routes make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests. You should
  # consider removing or commenting them out if you're using named routes and resources.
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end

**The mxml file looks like this:**

```
    private const CONTEXT_URL:String = "http://localhost:3000";

    private function addNewAccount():void {
        accounts.appendChild(<account><id></id><name>new name</name></account>);
    }


]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:HTTPService id="accountsIndex" url="{CONTEXT_URL}/accounts"
    resultFormat="e4x"
    result="accounts=event.result as XML" />

<mx:HTTPService id="accountsCreate" url="{CONTEXT_URL}/accounts"
    method="POST" resultFormat="e4x" contentType="application/xml"
    result="accountsIndex.send()" />

<mx:HTTPService id="accountsUpdate"
    url="{CONTEXT_URL}/accounts/{accountsGrid.selectedItem.id}?_method=put"
    method="POST" resultFormat="e4x" contentType="application/xml" />

<mx:HTTPService id="accountsDelete"
    url="{CONTEXT_URL}/accounts/destroy/{accountsGrid.selectedItem.id}"
    method="POST" resultFormat="e4x" contentType="application/xml"
    result="accountsIndex.send()" >
    <mx:request>
        <_method>
            destroy
        </_method>
    </mx:request>
</mx:HTTPService>   

<mx:DataGrid id="accountsGrid"
    dataProvider="{accounts.account}"
    editable="true">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Id" dataField="id" editable="false"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name" />
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

<mx:Button label="New"
    click="addNewAccount()"
    enabled="{accountsGrid.dataProvider!=null}" />

<mx:Button label="{accountsGrid.selectedItem.id==''?'Create':'Update'}"
    click="accountsGrid.selectedItem.id=='' ?
        accountsCreate.send(accountsGrid.selectedItem) :
        accountsUpdate.send(accountsGrid.selectedItem)" />

<mx:Button label="Delete"
    click="accountsGrid.selectedItem.id=='' ?
        accountsIndex.send() : accountsDelete.send()"
    enabled="{accountsGrid.selectedItem!=null}" />
```